# USB Hub for Mining Rig

Tags: mining-hardware

I'm looking for 10-port, externally powered usb hubs.  I can provide all the current at 5V that I'd need though and thus would NOT like it to come with an ac adapter.

Is there anything like this?

A common one sold by different people seems to be:
http://amzn.to/1aB89i1
http://amzn.to/1cjfXq1

But the one I got is not consistently being recognized by a linux box (doesn't show up in output of lsusb).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bitcoin.SE. While we do encourage people to come here with all their Bitcoin questions, there are sadly a few that are too subjective or don't fit our format very well. This is one of them. We encourage you to read through the FAQ and keep on participating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can personally recommend your second link, the [CE Compass 10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00825QQQC).  I have used 4 of them, and they work equally well in Windows, Debian, and BAMT.

Answer (score 1):

I  use the [Anker 9 Port USB 3.0 Hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NGQWL2). I have 3 of these and they are 100% flawless. Remember you get what you pay for, and these are the best.